# GIT push changes from Master to all other branches Devops /Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-branch, git-merge

I'm using *Visual Studio 17* and *DevOps* on *Visualstudio.com* to interface with Git

I have several branches to work on different features.
We just Merged **Branch C** back into master.

Now, as you can see, master is ahead of some of the newer branches (bottom).

Master branch should be bare minimum for all other (unlocked) branches. How do we force all branches to have everything from master without overwriting their new changes?

[image: Devops visualstudio.com Branch Screen]

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pulling?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#update-your-branch-with-the-latest-changes-from-master

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

1. git reset to commit when `Branch B` has been merged do develop
2. On branches X and Y pull changes from `master`
3. Merge branches X and Y to `master`
4. On `Branch C` pull changes from branch `master`
5. Again merge `Branch C` to branch `master`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simple merge *from* master to each branch *individually*.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this in bulk

[image: how to]
[image: new display]